# Java Inheritance constructor trouble

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to implement a program in Java that has a parent class RoundShapes and two children Sphere and Cone. When I try to make a constructor in my child classes it gives me an error that the constructor cannot be applied to that given type. 
    I then researched and found a tutorial on inheritance and they used a super constructor. I tried to use that but now it gives me an error that radius can't be used before the super constructor?! I didn't in the scope of the constructor so I am not sure what that is indicating.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Miller_A03Q4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere();
        RoundShape cone1 = new RoundShape();
        RoundShape.setRadius(4);

    }




    public static class RoundShape{
         double area;
         double volume;
         double radius;
         String shape;       
        //            
        public RoundShape(double r){

          radius = r;

        }
        // set radius method
       public  void setRadius(double r){
           radius = r;
       }   
       // get area method
       public double getArea(){
           return area;
       }
       // get volume
       public double getVolume(){
           return volume;


    }
    }   
       // sphere is-a from roundshape
    static class Sphere extends RoundShape{

        public Sphere(double r){
            radius = r;

        }
         //set area 
         public void setArea(){
         area = 4 * Math.PI * radius * radius;

         } 






        // get volume
        public void setVolume(){
        volume = (4/3) * Math.PI * radius * radius * radius;        

    }

    }

    //cone class is-a from roundshape
    class Cone extends RoundShape{
        double height;

        //set area
        public void setArea(){
            area = Math.PI * radius * (radius + Math.sqrt( height * height + radius * radius));

    } 
// cone volume
        public void setVolume(){
            volume = Math.PI * radius * radius * (height/3);

    } 
}


}
```

Comment: @AndrewL. They are called static inner-classes, and they are a language feature.

Comment: @4castle really? I guess you learn something new everyday

Answer (score 0):

All constructors make a call to their super class's constructor before calling their own constructor by calling `super()`. If you leave out the call to `super()`, it inserts the call implicitly.

In your case, you did not specify a constructor in your super class that takes 0 parameters, so Java is unable to infer what the parameters for `super()` should be, and so it throws a compiler error and asks for you to specify what those parameters should be.

To fix your code, you have 2 options

1. Create a constructor in `RoundShape` that takes 0 parameters.
2. Make an explicit call to `super()` in which you specify the parameters.

Option #2 would look like this. Note that the call to `super()` must come before any other statements.

```
public Sphere(double r) {
    super(r);
    // other statements here
}
```

Comment: @ 4castle Thank you for the help!  I had super(radius) instead of super(r)....smh.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions on this forum and some additional research, I was able to correct my program. I also had several run time errors in my original code that was posted, so I wanted to provide the updated code in case a total newbie like me stumbles across this.

Some majors were: 1. I didn't need to include setArea() and setVolume() methods but instead placed the formula in getArea() and getVolume(). 2. I didn't need to include volume and area in my constructors. 3. I also included a toString() method so I could access my data.

I am sure this is far from the best and most efficient code but it seems to work. I have provided my new and updated code below for reference. Thanks to everyone who tolerates my dumb questions!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Miller_A03Q4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sphere sphere1 = new Sphere(4);
        Cone cone1 = new Cone(3,7);
        System.out.println(cone1.toString());
        System.out.println(sphere1.toString());
        cone1.setHeight(10);
        sphere1.setRadius(3);
        System.out.println(cone1.toString());
        System.out.println(sphere1.toString());



    }



// parent Roundhape
    public static class RoundShape{
         double area;
         double volume;
         double radius;
         String shape;
         double height;
        //            
        //constructor
        public RoundShape(double r){

          radius = r;

        }
        // set radius method
       public  void setRadius(double r){
           radius = r;
       }   
       // get area method
       public double getArea(){
           return area;
       }
       // get volume
       public double getVolume(){
           return volume;


    }
       //toString
         public String toString(){
            return "Shape: " + shape +" Radius: " + radius + " Height: "
                    + height+ " Volume: " + this.getVolume() + " Area: "+ this.getArea();


        }   
    }   
       // sphere is-a from roundshape
    public static class Sphere extends RoundShape{
        //constructor
        public Sphere(double r){
            super(r);
            radius = r;
            shape = "sphere";


        }
        //get area
        public double getArea(){

               area = 4 * Math.PI * radius * radius;
                return area;
       }
       // get volume
       public double getVolume(){

           volume = 4 * Math.PI * (radius * radius * radius)/3;
           return volume;
    }
    }
    //cone class is-a from roundshape
    public static class Cone extends RoundShape{

        // cone with radius and height
        public Cone(double r, double h){
            super(r);
            radius = r;
            height = h;
            shape = "cone";


        }
        //set height
        public void setHeight(double h){
            height = h;
        }
        // get area
        public double getArea(){

               area = Math.PI * radius * (radius + Math.sqrt( height * height + radius * radius));
                return area;
       }
       // get volume
       public double getVolume(){

           volume = Math.PI * radius * radius * (height/3);
           return volume;
    }
}


}
```